# Retrieving JSON information from Google Custom Search API using ruby

Tags: ruby, json, rest

I'm currently using Google's RESTful Custom Search API in order to retrieve Google custom search results in the JSON format. My code looks something like this:

```
require 'uri'
require 'net/http'

params = "key=#{key}&cx=#{cx}&q=#{query}&alt=#{alt}"
uri = "https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?#{params}"
r = Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse(uri).host, URI.parse(uri).path)

temp_file = 'testfile.html'
File.open(temp_file, 'w') { |f| f.write(r.body) }
`firefox #{temp_file}`
```

With the key, cx, query and alt variables all having been given suitable values. Now, when I copy and paste the uri string into my browser, I get back the JSON information I was expecting. However, when I try run the code, Firefox opens a page containing only the following message:

```
{"error":{"errors":[{"domain":"global","reason":"sslRequired","message":"SSL is required    to perform this operation."}],"code":403,"message":"SSL is required to perform this operation."}}
```

This message also appears if I try running `puts r.body` instead of writing to file and opening in the browser. Can someone tell me what's going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Net::HTTP uses http without SSL (https) by default. You can see the instructions here:
http://www.rubyinside.com/nethttp-cheat-sheet-2940.html under "SSL/HTTPS request"

```
require 'uri'
require 'net/https'

params = "key=#{key}&cx=#{cx}&q=#{query}&alt=#{alt}"
uri = URI.parse("https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?#{params}")

http= Net::HTTP.new(uri.host,uri.port)
http.use_ssl = true
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
r=http.request(Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri))

temp_file = 'testfile.html'
File.open(temp_file, 'w') { |f| f.write(r.body) }
`firefox #{temp_file}`
```

Comment: I get the following error message when I try run that code: undefined method `use_ssl=' for #<Net::HTTP www.googleapis.com:443 open=false> (NoMethodError)

Comment: My mistake, I had 'net/http' instead of 'net/https'

Comment: Yeah, sorry, that part was subtle.